# Next js app (running inside a docker container) fails to load static file images located in public dir

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

I am trying to run a next js app locally inside a docker file. When I run the container, everything works as expected with the exception of my image files failing to render on the page. Inspection via the developer tools indicates a failed network request for those images (no 4XX code is indicated). The failed request looks as follows:

[image]

When I build `npm run build` and run the app locally `npm run start`, I see this same request successfully run. Same success story when I run in development mode `npm run dev`.

Here is the section of code utilizing the next Image module. `import Image from "next/image";`

```
  <Image
    src="/images/computerStation.png"
    alt=""
    height={300}
    width={600}
  />
```

And my public directory tree:

```
root   
│
└───public
    │   
    └───images
        │
        └───computerStation.png
```

Given my local build/dev-env success, my thought is that I am doing something wrong with my docker file. I pretty much just ripped this off from the Next js docs and tweaked it to run with npm instead of yarn. See Dockerfile below:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
RUN chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/.next
USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
RUN npx next telemetry disable

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your docker Node version, which should be

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps

FROM node:14-alpine AS builder

FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
```

Next.js has some problems, in Node 16 (node:alpine).

Comment: That worked, thank you! I must have missed that in the docs.